# Swift : Segue Taped menu item's name on navigation bar title with SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue, swrevealviewcontroller

I want to pass the title of pressed item on SWRC menu to be the title of navigation bar of sw_front

So two VC :
1- side Menu  "sw_rear"
2- front VC  "sw_front"

```
class menuVC: UITableViewController {

var menu = ["Title1","Title2","Title3"]
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.textLabel?.text = menu[indexPath.row]

    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "Pushitem"
        {
            if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? frontVC{
                destinationVC.NavBar.topItem?.title = menu[indexPath.row]
            }
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `prepareForSegue` method has to be implemented outside of the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, the array should be filled inside of the life cycle..

```
  var menu = [String]()   //<---- declare the array Globally 

 @IBOutlet weak var mytableview:UITableView!     //<---- connect this outlet to your tableview

override viewDidLoad()
{
  super.viewDidLoad()
 menu = ["Pathology","Biochem","Physiology"]   //<----- fill the array into the life cycle
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
cell.textLabel?.text = menu[indexPath.row]
   return cell
}


 func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Pushitem"
    {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? frontVC{
          var indexPath = self.mytableview.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell)!  //<---- you could get the indexPath of the cell 
            destinationVC.NavBar.topItem?.title = menu[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: xcode suggest adding override to prepareForSegue then after that it crashes > fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value > pointed to destinationVC.NavBar.topItem?.title = menu[indexPath.row]

Comment: try something like `var title = menu[indexPath.row]` then assign title to destination title

Comment: I did but didn't work please if you take a look https://www.dropbox.com/s/16wd7l8fjj6ulf2/TwoSWRE.zip?dl=0

Comment: you forgot to add the **IBOutlet** and connect to your storyboard UITableView, because we need it for this line `var indexPath = self.mytableview.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell)!`

Comment: so set up a breakpoint ` destinationVC.NavBar.topItem?.title = menu[indexPath.row]` to see if there is a value in the array

Comment: replace the indexPath with `var indexPath = self.mytableview.indexPathForSelectedRow()!`

Comment: you mean like this 'var indexPath = self.mytableview.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
                destinationVC.NavBar.topItem?.title = menu[indexPath]'

Comment: `var indexPath = self.mytableview.indexPathForSelectedRow()! destinationVC.NavBar.topItem?.title = menu[indexPath.row]`

Comment: second line error definition conflict with previous value

Comment: you have to replace the two previous with the new one

Comment: I think the error bc front VC in viewDidLoad  self.NavBar.topItem?.title = "" but I when I change it to self.NavBar.topItem?.title = menu I got error and I can't access indexpath in viewdidload

Comment: so wait you just want to show the item into the title of the new controller right ? if yes you could do  destinationVC.title = menu[indexPath.row]

Comment: yes , I did it > no crash but it is fixed to the title 'Physiology' no changes to other title its fixed

Comment: you should clean the project, and make sure in the viewDidLoad() of the destination controller is empty for now